# What is this component designated as PTC?

Tags: components, identification

What is this component designated as "PTC3"?

[image]

Comment: what device is this PCB from?

Comment: If it says PTC then my first guess would be it's a [PTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor#PTC_(positive_temperature_coefficient)).

Comment: Positive Temperature Coefficient aka "resettable fuse" protection components at Digikey

Comment: Figured it out. The first thing I did was google PTC, but it didn't come back with anything that resembled that form factor. After a bunch more digging, I found it: [Bourns MF-SM050](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bourns/MF-SM050-2?qs=QW4jRO6c0NNXoOWhcQ%252busA%3D%3D)

Comment: Looks like a Bourns part.

Comment: fyi: i recently replaced one of those in my refrigerator ... there, it is used instead of a mechanical starting relay on the compressor ... it is a flat disk that looks like a coin cell

Comment: looks like an obsolete Bourns (B) part. They make them smaller in SMD now.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Post an answer and I'll close this one out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positive Temperature Coefficient aka "resettable fuse" protection components at Digikey .

I have seen these used on 48V series LED boost regulators to act as resettable fuse on the SMPS for short circuit protection.

As noted above it was made by Bourns but may be obsolete replaced with smaller offerings in SMD with faster response time.

[image]